# Fail to run flutter with image_picker: ^0.6.7+9

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker, flutter-packages

I've got this error after adding image_picker: ^0.6.7+9 to my pubspec.yaml file and I'm already in AndroidX since my android/gradle.properties file has the androidX properties, as said in this documentation 'https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration'.

But I get this error anyway, and after searching and trying solutions for hours, I still unable to fix it.

Here is the error message.

C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:8: error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
^
C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
^
symbol:   class Lifecycle
location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: I have this issue since Friday with the previous version of the image_picker. Still can't find the fix but I will keep a close eye on this post either for someone to post a solution or I'll post it once I find it

Comment: Try changing in pubspec.lock the flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle version to 1.0.2

Comment: @Rombus I changed the version in pubspec.lock to 1.0.2, but when I run the project it revert to 1.0.9 automatically.

Comment: @Rombus I found an answer that worked for me, maybe it will works for you too.

Comment: That didn't work for me. My issue was related to this plugin in conjunction with others on a bigger app. If I created a small app just to test, it will work with no problem. What I ended up doing is removing image_picker and using christian_picker_image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed 'compileSdkVersion' and 'targetSdkVersion' to 29 and worked. (before was 28)
You can find these properties in 'android/app/build.gradle'

Answer (score 0):

It's 2021- Apparently downgrading compilesdk and targetsdk to 29 worked like charm